# How to colorize the clicked class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to colorize the clicked class but it colorizes every class. Please check. If he clicks 4. li colorize it blue etc.

```
<li class="msg-chat-message msg-user-message"><span class="msg-body">sa</span></li>
<li class="msg-chat-message msg-user-message"><span class="msg-body">sa</span></li>
<li class="msg-chat-message msg-user-message"><span class="msg-body">sa</span></li>
<li class="msg-chat-message msg-user-message"><span class="msg-body">sa</span></li>
<li class="msg-chat-message msg-user-message"><span class="msg-body">sa</span></li>

$('.msg-body').click(function() {
    $('.msg-body').css('color','red')
});
```

It colorizes every msg-body.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select only the element that is clicked:

```
$('.msg-body').click(function() {
    $(this).css('color','red');
});
```

Comment: WOW. I never thought it would be that easy. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, please consider marking my answer as correct :-)

Answer (score 1):

As you have all same classes...use **this** reference

```js
$('.msg-body').click(function() {
   $(this).css('color','red')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="msg-chat-message msg-user-message"><span class="msg-body">sa</span></li>
<li class="msg-chat-message msg-user-message"><span class="msg-body">sa</span></li>
<li class="msg-chat-message msg-user-message"><span class="msg-body">sa</span></li>
<li class="msg-chat-message msg-user-message"><span class="msg-body">sa</span></li>
<li class="msg-chat-message msg-user-message"><span class="msg-body">sa</span></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are very good, and show how you can change the css color of a message. However, I expect that what you really want to do is mark these messages as selected, so that you can then do something with them...

If your needs end at changing the color of the text then stop reading! The rest of this is excessive... although you might want to think about using `.toggleClass()` for your text color changes.

---

## Explaination

The code below adds a click event to the message wrapper `.msg-chat-message` and adds a class `.selected`. CSS styling then highlights the text of *any* of it's children as red using the lines below (this may be a bit broad for you, but you can make it more selective):

```
.msg-chat-message.selected * {
  color: red;
}
```

I've added a delete button which removes any selected messages, and a second button that 'favourites' them by adding a class with new styling.

Cycling through `.selected` messages is then easy with the jquery below:

```
$(".msg-chat-message.selected").each( function() {
  // Do something here
  // You can use $(this) to make changes to the individual elements
});
```

---

## Demo

```js
// Add click event to the parent wrapper
$('.msg-chat-message').click(function() {

    // Add selected class to this element
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");
    
});


// Add click event to the delete button
$("#delete").click( function() {

  // Delete all the selected messages
  $(".msg-chat-message.selected").remove();
  
});



// Add click event to the delete button
$("#favourite").click( function() {

  // Cycle through each selected item
  $(".msg-chat-message.selected").each( function() {
    $(this).addClass("favourite")
  });
  
  // Deselect all the selected messages
  $(".msg-chat-message.selected").removeClass("selected");

});
```

```css
.msg-chat-message.selected * {
  color: red;
}

.msg-chat-message.favourite * {
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li class="msg-chat-message msg-user-message"><span class="msg-body">Message 1</span></li>
<li class="msg-chat-message msg-user-message"><span class="msg-body">Message 2</span></li>
<li class="msg-chat-message msg-user-message"><span class="msg-body">Message 3</span></li>
<li class="msg-chat-message msg-user-message"><span class="msg-body">Message 4</span></li>
<li class="msg-chat-message msg-user-message"><span class="msg-body">Message 5</span></li>

<button id="delete">Delete Selected</button>

<button id="favourite">Favourite message</button>
```